# Allow apache to access a folder but deny access to other users

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

I have a symlink in my /var/www/ folder that points to a folder in my home directory. I had to set the "other" permissions on the folder to read/execute in order to get files to show up when visiting the server via a web browser, but this allows access to the folder by other users. I want apache to be able to access this folder, but I also want to deny read/write/execute to any other users (other than apache and myself). How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

The apache service belongs to the user www-data, so I just added www-data to my own user group and then restarted apache!